# eCommerce Website running on Desktop plus BrowserStack mobile device farm emulator, tested using Selenium v4.16.1 and Java having Selenium code issues

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mobile, desktop-application, selenium4

Ours is a eCommerce web site with SAP as the back end. **Our Customers use the desktop version, and on mobile platform as well**.

For this reason, we **test our site both on desktop** and specifically **on mobile** using BrowserStack cloud device farm.

The web site **source code is same(made with `node.js with vue.js,nuxt.js`) on both the plaforms - desktop as well as mobile**. We use **Selenium v4.16.1 with Java** code to test automate the web site on mobile browsers. Desktop Chrome Browser allows few mobile profiles(`Open dev tools + click an toggle device tool bar icon at top left side Ctrl+Shift+M`) for mimicking the running the site on a Mobile device.

Issues arise like location permission Browser pop ups can't be answered (using Browser options class) and Actions class is not effective on drop down menus.

- Chrome Options class is in-effective in responding to location permission Browser pop-up
- **Actions class alone is not useful**, in order to click a drop-down menu item. `Should retrieve the entire menu item list, iterate and use **JavaScriptExecutor** to select a specific menu item`

**`Apart from these issues, for having a comprehensive approach for testing this set up, is there a prescribed approach for going about testing ?`**

I am familiar with native mobile app testing using Appium, even though it does not apply for this case. Thanks for advise and insights.

Comment: Since you mentioned that you are trying to tackle the pop-ups for your tests and you are running your tests on BrowserStack. Have you tried using the methods prescribed in this documentation: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/handle-permission-pop-ups ?

Comment: @grandEL-dsouza
Thanks. A good resource. I will check it out.